# Replace double period to single and if 4 or more replace to three

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

If there is two periods(..) replace with one (.) and if there is four or more period(....) replace it with three(...).

Require both option working at same time

i try this way

```
var fieldval = test..
fieldval = fieldval.replace(/\.{2}/g, '.')
```

Output

```
test. (with single dot)

var fieldval = test.....
fieldval = fieldval.replace(/\.{4,}/g, '...');
```

output

```
test... (with three dot)
```

Both the option should work together. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to to have a single regex,you can use

```
input.replace(/([^.]|^)(?:([.])[.]|([.]{3})[.]+)(?![.])/g, "$1$2$3");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
fieldval = fieldval.replace(
    /\.{2,}/g, 
    function(val){ 
        return val.length == 2 ? '.' : '...';
    }
);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XUjX5/)